# Can vim echo the contents of a register without treating linefeed(^@) characters as "Enter" key press?

Tags: unix, vim, vi

I have some lines of text I'm trying to enter into register and then echo the contents of the register to the terminal which spawned the vim process, so that the text will be visible in the terminal window after vim is exited.

I can get this to work fine with a single line of text, but as soon as a newline/linebreak is added, all attempts to do this fail.

Using an example file containing:

1 a
  2 ab
  3 abc
  4 abce
  5 abcef
  6 abcefg

First I put the file contents into a register("m) via ":%y m"
Then I try to ":exe '!echo '@m"

This echos the first line of text to the terminal

a

But vim treats the first line feed/break following the letter "a" like an Enter key press so that it throws the following error message

E492: Not an editor command: abce^@abcef^@abcefg^@^@

I run the following commands in ":debug" mode hoping to substitute the ^@ characters with a newline(\n)

:echo substitute(strtrans(@m),"^@",'\n',"g")
:echo substitute(strtrans(@m),'^@','\n',"g")

I've tried double and single quotes, and I've tried typing the caret symbol and ampersand Literally, as well as using the special character CTRL-V+CTRL-J
Unfortunately in Debug mode I can see that the output is always the following:

a^@ab^@abc^@abce^@abcef^@abcefg^@^@

The same happens with printf.
I've done some brushing up on the ambiguities of newlines, null characters, and how vim treats these within registers, but am stuck with an unclear understanding whether what I'm trying to achieve is plausible.

Comment: I have been able to get around this issue using the command:"!cat %" instead of echo. It does require having to save the file first so it has a name, which is not ideal for my case as the file may contain sensitive info.

I am still very curious to know why my attempts with echo failed and why the substitute function does not replace the ^@ character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`:h nl-used-for-nul` explains that the newline character `'\n'` is displayed by Vim as `^@`. So, yes, as you already said, you send actual newline characters to the shell.

Next, the general idea of replacing the one character `'\n'` (ASCII 0x0a) by the two characters `"\n"` (0x5c 0x6e) is correct as well. You want the shell to receive `foo\nbar`.

```
:echo substitute(@m, '\n', '\n', 'g')
a
ab
abc
abce
abcef
abcefg
```

The output obviously still contains actual newline characters, so we have to escape these.

```
:echo substitute(@m, '\n', '\\n', 'g')
a\nab\nabc\nabce\nabcef\nabcefg\n
```

This looks good! So, let's try the whole command you had in mind:

```
:execute '!echo' substitute(@m, '\n', '\\n', 'g')
anabnabcnabcenabcefnabcefgn

Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

Hmm? Well, `:execute` evaluates strings and therefore *consumes* "one level of strings". Thus we have to escape our newlines once more whereas we have to *double* the amount of escapes for each "level of strings".

So, we don't just need `a\nab\nabc`, we need `a\\nab\\nabc`:

```
:echo substitute(@m, '\n', '\\\\n', 'g')
a\\nab\\nabc\\nabce\\nabcef\\nabcefg\\n

:execute '!echo' substitute(@m, '\n', '\\\\n', 'g')
a
ab
abc
abce
abcef
abcefg


Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

Additional notes:

- When using double quotes, which process escape characters, opposed to single quoted strings, we would have to double the amount of escapes again: `substitute(@m, '\n', "\\\\\\\\n", 'g')`.
- If you want to strip off the trailing newline, use `trim(@)`.

Comment: Thanks @mhinz this is such a clear breakdown and great examples!

Answer (score 3):

I think you are looking for `shellescape()`:

```
:execute "!echo " . shellescape(@@, 1)
```

With a non-zero-arg as the second argument the `<NL>` character is also escaped.

For more help see:

```
:h shellescape()
```